# Deleting iCloud account with no password entered on the iCloud page

Tags: icloud, iphone

The password for my iCloud account has not been entered on the iCloud page under settings and I don't know what it is and therefore because it's not already entered on the iCloud page I am not able to follow the instructions to turn off

Find my iPhone without the password. I need to turn off Find my iPhone in order to delete my iCloud account.

iPhone 5 and iOS is 8.0.2.

Any suggestions what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You could reset your apple id password at [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com). After you did this you should be able to turn off "find my iPhone" in icloud's settings

Comment: i can't reset my appleid because it asks whether it should reset by email or security questions. can't access email because i don't have the password. i don't know the answers to the security questions.

Comment: Than you should contact applecare. They could also reset your password when you do nat have two-step vertification enabled. On this page, http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232 , you can find the phone number for your country.